# transform ddmmyyyy to dd/mm/yyyy and sort

Tags: excel

I've got a spreadsheet with a tonne of dates all in the ddmmyyyy format e.g. 01012012, is there a simple way to transform this into a nice date format? Also to then sort those dates so that the latest year is first, but arranged by earliest month e.g.

```
01.02.2016    
05.04.2016    
01.02.2015    
20.06.2015    
10.08.2015
```

Thanks!

Comment: do you have preference for any language, please you should add this

Answer (score 0):

you can try this one, just block your cell then right click and choose format cell, custom and edit like image i share

[this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6gf2W.png)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that Excel is storing your dates as text rather than parsing them as dates (in which case jaro21's answer will help you), then you would place the following formula in column B:

```
=DATE(RIGHT(A2,4),MID(A2,3,2),LEFT(A2,2))
```

Assuming that your dates are in column A starting at row 2 then this formula would convert them into Excel serial date that you can then format anyway you want (again jaro21 will help you from here).

Sadly for the second part of your question for your dates you can only sort oldest to newest or newest to oldest. You can't have a 2 way sort first on year then on month number. To do this you would need 2 helper columns. First one would have the formula copied down:

```
=YEAR(B1)
```

Second column would be:

```
=MONTH(B1)
```

Then you would first sort ascending on the month column and then on descending on the year column. Now all your rows would be sorted by the year
first and then by month. Regards.